# Difference between JavaScriptMVC and CanJs

Tags: javascript, javascriptmvc, canjs

Call me stupid, but I'm quite confused. Are they the same and can.js is simply its successor? They seem to share quite a lot of functionality. As JavaScriptMVC is not updated as regulary as CanJs I think about switching to the latter. Does anyone have experiences with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CanJS is the next version of what used to be the MVC parts of jQueryMX which is part of JavaScriptMVC. It will replace jQueryMX in the next JavaScriptMVC release but is maintained by the same team and shares most of the ideas with some modern features like live-binding and Mustache templates.

The main idea is for CanJS to be usable whichever way you prefer, as a single library, as AMD modules with RequireJS or in context of the other tools that JavaScriptMVC provides ([jQuery++](http://jquerypp.com/), [Steal](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!stealjs), [FuncUnit](http://funcunit.com/), [DocumentJS](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!DocumentJS)) for a full stack application framework (not and MVC framework). So if you are just starting out, I definitely recommend using CanJS as it will be a part of JavaScriptMVC very soon.

Comment: Thank's alot for pointing that out! Would you recommend switching on a currently developed project? And if yes, are there any guides yet for handling the migration process?

Comment: Depends on how far you are. There is a jQueryMX to CanJS compatibility layer in the jQuery++ repository https://github.com/bitovi/jquerypp which should make migration easier but there isn't an official migration guide yet. It will be available with the 3.3 release.

Comment: Is there a guide how to use CanJS with StealJS? I like both to be together. Updating both from git repo seems a bit hassle.

Comment: You should just be able to clone CanJS and Steal (or add them as a submodule), include `steal.js` and `steal('can')`.